# .NET BeginTransaction fails on IBM.Data.DB2 provider

Tags: c#, transactions, db2, database-connection, informix

I've got a connection to Informix DB (providerName="IBM.Data.DB2") and it fails on

```
Transaction = Connection.BeginTransaction();
```

I tried all possible isolation modes, e.g.

```
Transaction = Connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
Transaction = Connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
etc...
```

It fails on each one of available isolation levels. However when I try to bypass this and execute some sql without a transaction, it works.

Any help would be appreciated.

--

Additional info:
Informix returns error when trying to open the connection in .NET code
"!!! ERROR [HY011] [IBM] CLI0126E Operation invalid at this time. SQLSTATE=HY011"
There is not much info online on this error, and I tried increasing the size of the physical log file, checking user privileges, running as an admin.

The DB access is from .NET code that is Flient Migrator (https://github.com/eoin55/fluentmigrator). Eventually I ended up recompiling it from source after adding extensive logging in order to locate the issue and narrowed it down to the Connection.BeginTransaction statement.

Comment: What platform & version of Db2?  What's the error message?

Comment: Is your Informix database created with logging ('Non-buffered', 'Buffered' or 'ANSI')? You can only do transactions in a db created with logging.   Run something like "select * from sysmaster:sysdatabases where name='stores7';"  ('stores7' is the dbname here). It should tell you if it has logging or not.

Comment: @J_S That was it,. Post it as an answer. 


The solution was to change this CREATE DATABASE bn_name; to this: CREATE DATABASE WITH BUFFERED LOG;